# How do I properly install protoc-gen-go on Ubuntu?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, go, protocol-buffers

I managed to download and install Go on Ubuntu. However, I'm currently unable to set up protoc-gen-go properly because my GOPATH and GOROOT are not properly defined. Here's what my GOROOT and GOPATH look like:

```
export GOROOT=/usr/local/go
export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin
export GOPATH=$HOME/go
export GOBIN=$GOPATH/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT:$GOPATH:$GOBIN
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin"
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
export GO_PATH=~/go
export PATH=$PATH:/$GO_PATH/bin
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove all of these lines, and replace them with:

```
#export GOROOT=/usr/local/go # this should not be needed
export GOPATH=$HOME/go
export GOBIN=$GOPATH/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT:$GOPATH:$GOBIN
```

No need to export PATH so many times..

Also using `~` in `export GO_PATH=~/go` can cause issues.

Once you add the lines to `.bashrc` reload your terminal, or execute these same lines in the terminal, so they take effect.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I followed this tutorial to make sure that everything was working properly.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uaMyiOFXs5U

Comment: I was advised not to export GOROOT because it can cause Go to stop working when you have more than one version of it. You only need to add this to the .bashrc file.
`export GOPATH=$HOME/go`
`export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin:$GOPATH/bin`

Go will work without adding GOROOT